# Tuning the php mysql search query with implode function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am executing a PHP mysql search query on whatever user types in search box with implode function.The query works fine,but i want to change it a bit,because its not giving me correct results.Please have a look at the query

```
$lcSearchVal=$_GET['name'];
$lcSearcharr=explode("-",$lcSearchVal);
foreach( $lcSearcharr as $lcSearchWord ){
$lcSearchWord = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $lcSearchWord);
$lcSearchWord = preg_replace('/%/', '\%', $lcSearchWord);
    $parts[] = '`Description` LIKE "% '.$lcSearchWord.'%"';
    $parts1[] = '`Description` LIKE "% '.$lcSearchWord.' %"';
}

$qry='SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  ('.implode ('AND',$parts).')';
```

first of all i m getting the search whatever user has typed in search box in second page from first line in code above.Then i m splitting that variable into array by splitting them with hyphens in search.Then i m executing a foreach loop on that array,which is used in sql query

For example:-
User searches as-Men casual shoes in first page.
I will get it in second page like Men-casual-shoes.
Then i will put them in an array like with three elements as men,casual,shoes.
Then i will execute search query which i have written above,which will form like as follows

```
select * from table_name where (Description like '%men %' and Description like '%casual %' and Description like '%shoes %')
```

But i want the query should look like as follows

```
select * from table_name where (Description like '%men %' and Description like '%casual %') or (Description like '%casual %' and Description like '%shoes %') or (Description like '%men %' and Description like '%shoes %')
```

Please help on tuning the query

Comment: Description is one of the column names in table where i m executing like query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 `for` loops to enumerate all combinations:

```
<?php
$s = "men-casual-shoes";
$ss = explode('-', $s);
$parts = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ss)-1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < count($ss); $j++) {
        # You may want to do mysqli_real_escape_string here
        $w1 = str_replace('%', '\%', $ss[$i]);
        $w2 = str_replace('%', '\%', $ss[$j]);
        $parts[] = "(`description` like '% $w1 %' and `description` like '% $w2 %')";
    }
}

$qry = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  ('.implode (' or ',$parts).')';
echo $qry;
```

prints

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  ((`description` like '% men %' and `description` like '% casual %') or (`description` like '% men %' and `description` like '% shoes %') or (`description` like '% casual %' and `description` like '% shoes %'))
```

Comment: Thanks man for timely help,but when i type single word in variable s,like variable s=men.then the solution fails.Please check once

Comment: you can add an if statement to check if there is only one word, then build the query accordingly